# Issue with LibPng (incomplete type, forward references) on Snow Leopard

Tags: c++, g++, libpng

I am using MAC OS Snow Leopard and have tried to compile my program, a1.cpp, but I seem to have trouble with the linking libpng. Is this my issue? If not, what is? And, how can I resolve it?
Thanks in advance

```
ew-host-2:a1 gifford$ make

 g++ -O3 -o a1 a1.cpp -I . -L/opt/local/lib -lpng
 In file included from a1.cpp:2:0:
./SImageIO.h: In static member function 'static void SImageIO::read_png_file(const char*, SDoublePlane&, SDoublePlane&, SDoublePlane&)':
./SImageIO.h:97:23: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'png_info {aka struct png_info_def}'
In file included from ./SImageIO.h:21:0,
             from a1.cpp:2:
/opt/local/include/png.h:566:16: error: forward declaration of 'png_info {aka struct png_info_def}'
In file included from a1.cpp:2:0:
./SImageIO.h:98:24: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'png_info {aka struct png_info_def}'
In file included from ./SImageIO.h:21:0,
             from a1.cpp:2:
/opt/local/include/png.h:566:16: error: forward declaration of 'png_info {aka struct png_info_def}'
In file included from a1.cpp:2:0:
./SImageIO.h:99:28: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'png_info {aka struct png_info_def}'
In file included from ./SImageIO.h:21:0,
             from a1.cpp:2:
/opt/local/include/png.h:566:16: error: forward declaration of 'png_info {aka struct png_info_def}'
In file included from a1.cpp:2:0:
./SImageIO.h:100:27: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'png_info {aka struct png_info_def}'
In file included from ./SImageIO.h:21:0,
             from a1.cpp:2:
/opt/local/include/png.h:566:16: error: forward declaration of 'png_info {aka struct png_info_def}'
In file included from a1.cpp:2:0:
./SImageIO.h:113:43: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'png_info {aka struct png_info_def}'
In file included from ./SImageIO.h:21:0,
             from a1.cpp:2:
/opt/local/include/png.h:566:16: error: forward declaration of 'png_info {aka struct png_info_def}'
In file included from ./SImage.h:4:0,
             from a1.cpp:1:
./DTwoDimArray.h: In instantiation of '_DTwoDimArray<T>& _DTwoDimArray<T>::operator=(const _DTwoDimArray<T>&) [with T = double]':
./SImage.h:9:7:   required from here
./DTwoDimArray.h:84:7: error: 'memcpy' was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
In file included from ./SImage.h:5:0,
             from a1.cpp:1:
 /usr/include/string.h:83:7: note: 'void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)' declared here, later in the translation unit
```

Comment: Can you please post the source code for your program? Without seeing the code you've written, we can't possibly help you.

Comment: If your program is making direct reference to members of the png_struct or png_info, you'll get errors of the type you showed error: invalid use of incomplete type 'png_info.... These references were allowed in libpng-1.2.x but not in libpng-1.5 or later. libpng-1.4 was a "transition" version which will show them as "deprecated" warnings, to help you rewrite your code to work with later libpng versions.